# Is an infinitive as a noun neuter in gender?

Tags: participle, gender, infinitive, compound-noun

On p37 in Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> The infinitive is an abstract verbal noun in the neuter singular. It
> is indeclinable; that  is, although it is a noun, it does not have
> case endings, and it has limited syntactic  functions. The infinitive
> has the verbal properties of tense (present, perfect, or future) and
> voice (active or passive). As noted in Section 7, the second principal
> part of every verb is the present active infinitive and is regularly
> translated "to ." For example: movere, "to move."

Does it say that an infinitive as a noun is neuter in gender?

But on p269, is it correct that the perfect passive infinitives and the future active infinitives are periphrastics, i.e. have compound forms? Does the participle in such a periphrastic have different forms for different genders, so does such an infinitive have different forms for different genders? For example,

- perfect passive infinitives: vocatus, a, um esse,
- future active infinitives: vocaturus, a, um esse.

Are "vocatus, a, um esse" three infinitives with genders masculine, feminine, and neuter respectively? So can an infinitive   have gender other than neuter? If all the three infinitives are neuter, when shall I use which of the three?

Or are "vocatus, a, um esse" three forms of the same infinitive, and the forms have genders masculine, feminine, and neuter respectively?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your own quote and screenshot say that the infinitive is a neuter noun and that the participles in the periphrastic infinitives are declined for gender. What isn't clear about it?

Comment: @Cairnarvon It's clearly confusing for the OP that there are two genders in play, and indeed, when the infinitive is used as a subject or object, it's not a trivial question what the gender of the declined part should be.

Answer (score 7):

It is best to distinguish between the 'true' infinitive (*esse, vocare, vinci*) and compound or periphrastic infinitives, which are really a construction of a participle plus the infinitive *esse* (*vocatus esse, victuram esse*).

The true infinitive is neuter:

> Errare humanum est "to err is human"

The gender of the 'fake' infinitive, i.e. the combination of participle with *esse*, is a complicated matter, if it has a gender at all. I believe it is normally considered to be neuter as well (see below).

However, inside the fake infinitive, we find a participle. And the participle must have a gender and case, which are those of whatever word it agrees with.

> Regina capta esse dicitur "the queen is said to have been captured"

> Dixit filias victuras esse "he said the daughters would win"

In impersonal constructions, the neuter singular participle is used:

> Audio ventum esse ad castra "I hear that *it was come to the army camp = I hear that one came to the army camp"

I believe any infinitival construction, including compound/fake infinitive and a.c.i., will be treated as neuter when needed:

> Deam victuram esse bonum est "that the goddess will win is good"

> Victum esse bonum est "having been defeated is good":

As in the last example, when the infinitive is meant in the general sense, without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with, I believe the participle will normally be neuter (*victum*). The infinitival construction (periphrastic infinitive) as a whole is also neuter.

Comment: "without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with, I believe the participle will normally be neuter (victum)" -- I'm pretty certain it's acc. masc. It is an angels-on-a-pinhead question as we will never be able to tell the difference in case of a particle, but we *can* tell the difference with other predicates, as in *Turpe est crudelem esse* &c.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Two related points: (i) unlike _ventum esse_, note that _crudelem esse_ is not an impersonal construction; (ii) unfortunately (at least for you), Cerberus exemplified the (intended) impersonal construction with an ambiguous example _victum esse bonum est_ (he intended _victum esse_ to be impersonal: “when the infinitive is meant in the general sense, without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with”). His last example is ambiguous since _victum esse_, unlike _ventum esse_, can be a personal passive or an impersonal one.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel The ambiguity is due to the fact that one can use the verb _vincere_ as transitive or intransitive (Cerberus intended it as intransitive here: _Deam victuram esse bonum est_ "that the goddess will win is good").
So, on the relevant (i.e. impersonal) reading of _victum esse_, i.e. on the same reading that an unambiguously impersonal passive has (e.g. _ventum esse ad castra_), Cerberus is right when saying that the participle is neuter. It's just the case he used an unfortunate example (his last one is ambiguous) to exemplify his point.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: That does look good to me as well, you're probably right, then. I tried to keep it a bit vague, was planning to look it up. I wonder now: does it perhaps also depend on the meaning of the word? *Iphigeniae placuit ?nuptum esse*? *Scripsit libro tertio de constructione magni referre ?stabilem esse*? Perhaps I feel that, when a certain type of entity comes to mind, the adjective or participle naturally attracts to it?

Comment: @Mitomino: You've seen through my ploy, I guess I was kind of deliberately ambiguous, seeming to illustrate both the impersonal infinitive and the gender of an infinitive without agreement, within the same example, which is not really possible. I must confess I just hadn't looked it up yet but simply chose an example that sounded good to me. What Sebastian suggested does mostly look good to me as well. (Now I wonder: what term should we use for periphrastic infinitives where the participle doesn't agree with anything, but isn't impersonal, i.e. the kind of construction I was supposed to show?)

Comment: I will improve my answer later.

Comment: @Cerberus Given the context you provided ("In impersonal constructions, the neuter singular participle is used... without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with, I believe the participle will normally be neuter"), I interpreted your last example as an impersonal construction: cf. also _ventum esse ad castra bonum est_. On THIS reading the participle of intransitive verbs (_venire_) or transitive verbs used as intransitives/unergatives (_vincere_) is neuter in the **impersonal** construction. Cf. _Pugnatum esse acriter bonum est_, where _pugnatum_ is neuter as well.

Comment: To both of you (Sebastian & Cerberus): The **impersonal** passive construction (again: only formed by intransitive/unergative verbs and transitive ones crucially used as intransitives) should not be mixed with the **personal** one _{victum/victam/victum} esse bonum est_ where the participle of a transitive (!) verb is masc., fem. neut., respectively. BTW, note that using a(n elliptical) indefinite pronoun as subject of the personal construction: _(quemdam) victum esse bonum est_ does not make it syntactically impersonal as _{ventum esse ad castra/pugnatum esse acriter} bonum est_.

Comment: @Mitomino the translation supplied by Cerberus himself made it clear that the personal construction was intended. Maybe you overlooked the "been." But in Latin alone, to be sure, it is ambiguous, and the question whether it is neut. or masc., like I said, is purely academic.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Yes, it's pretty obvious that the participle is masculine on the personal reading of _{quemdam/Caesarem/masc. elliptical subject} victum esse bonum est_. But this obvious point is not the one at issue here nor, probably, the one Cerberus wanted to make (in spite of his Engl. translation). I'm saying this because of what Cerberus says: "As in the last example, when the infinitive is meant in the general sense, without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with", which clearly points to the impersonal/subjectless reading of _victum esse_.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I’m sorry but I don't understand your second point: "the question whether it is neut. or masc., like I said, is purely academic". As I noted above, _victum_ is masculine on the personal reading of _{quemdam/Caesarem/masc. elliptical subject/...} victum esse bonum est_ and is neuter on the impersonal reading, where the subordinate clause lacks a subject (i.e. in Cerberus’s words:  “when the infinitive is meant in the general sense, without there being any primary argument for the participle to agree with").

Comment: Of course, the participle can also be neuter in the personal construction when the elliptical subject of the infinitival clause _victum esse_ refers to _oppidum_ or a neuter noun. But, again, this obvious point is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Mitomino Well, what can I do if you insist (and far beyond the requirements of clarity reiterate), in the face of clear evidence to the contrary and on the basis of a vague description that contains neither the word "impersonal" nor "passive," that this is clearly about the impersonal passive and my remarks are "irrelevant"? I'd just ask you to consider that the infinitive as a verbal noun offers its own mode of "impersonality" – both in the active and in the passive. Because when we say *errare humanum est*, we talk about the *concept* of erring, not about an actual instance where someone …

Comment: … errs. And why should we not extend this idea to an example like *nihil umquam ausum esse signum vitae futilis est* or something? It is, of course, not grammatically impersonal, but it would not be idiomatic to supply a subject for the infinitive.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Many thanks for your last clarification/comment & illuminating example. Now I see your relevant point and I realize that we've been talking at cross-purposes.